# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'

Tags: c#

I have following exception in the foreach loop

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type
>   'System.Data.DataRow'

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Pretty sure I can guess this one, but post your code first just in case. (The "foreach" loop.)

Comment: I removed the WPF tag, since the question has nothing to do with WPF

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A `DataRowView` is not a `DataRow`, and isn't convertible to a `DataRow`. However, you can access the corresponding `DataRow` using the `Row` property :

```
foreach(DataRowView drv in dataView)
{
    DataRow row = drv.Row;
    ...
}
```

Comment: foreach (DataRow dtrCurrentRow in (((System.Data.DataView)lstData.ItemsSource)).Table.Rows) { } I have used the above code to get my result, lstData is the listbox Control of wpf. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could also do this in one line using LINQ: `foreach (DataRow row in dataView.Select(drv => drv.Row))`

Comment: Eleven years later, still helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast like:

```
datarow= DirectCast (System.Data.DataRowView, System.Data.DataRow).row
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used `DataRow` as the foreach loop variable type while actually you are iterating enumerable with `DataRowView` type. Check if `DataRowView` has functionality that you need, if so you can just replace one with another. Or you can modify your code to return enumerable with `DataRow` instead of one with `DataRowView`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `foreach(DataRow dr in myDataView)`, try
`foreach(DataRowView drv in myDataView)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you try to do something like this

`DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;`

This Is How It Should Be Done

`System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord objData = (System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)e.Item.DataItem;`